# Error : vue-loader requires @vue/compiler-sfc to be present in the dependency tree

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to do

```
npm run serve
```

I have tried `npm update` `sudo npm serve`. It didn't work.
I also tried deleting the package-lock.json file and doing `npm install` after that, and that too didn't work. I also downgraded the version of the vue-loader to 15.9.2 and that also didn't work

Comment: have you tried `npm i @vue/compiler-sfc` ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use `vue-loader` from Vue 3 in Vue 2 project. Here is a versions I have for Vue 2 project – `vue: 2.6.14, vue-loader: 15.9.7, vue-template-compiler: 2.6.14, webpack: 5.42.0, webpack-cli: 4.7.2, webpack-dev-server: 3.11.2, @babel/core: 7.14.6, @babel/preset-env: 7.14.7, babel-loader: 8.2.2`.

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, you are missing the library so you just have to install it with

`npm i @vue/compiler-sfc`

Comment: My issue is that it's not mentioned in the `vue-loader` docs that this is necessary. The error is easy to miss, especially since `webpack` output tends to be very verbose because of all the dependent packages being included as well.

Comment: `npm i @vue/compiler-sfc --save-dev`

Answer (score 5):

This is a new thing in `vue-loader@16`. To fix this, assuming you are using Vue 2, you should downgrade:

```
yarn add vue-loader@15
```

Note that you also need `vue-template-compiler`, the same version as the version of Vue you are using.

Answer (score 4):

For us, the ones using VueJs 2!

Remember vue-loader@16 is only for VueJs 3.

Check the releases log
[here.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases)

I downgrade to the [v15.9.7](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v15.9.7). It is working fine.

If you are using Dependabot, can add the a ignore rule to avoid v16 PRs:

```
ignore:
  - dependency-name: "vue-loader"
    versions: ["16.x"]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this and this works for me

```
vue-loader@15.9.7
vue-template-compiler@2.6.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your problem has already been solved in one of the previous answers. But there is another *least likely* option in which you will receive a similar error.

The problem is in... `node` / `npm` versions. Possibly, some (non-LTS?) node/npm versions generates not quite correct dependency tree, and then trying to build unnecessary sources.

We got this error in one of our projects, when Jenkins built it on `node v11.14.0` and `npm 6.7.0`.
But same sources are built OK on `node v8.16.0` / `npm 6.4.1`, `node v10.18.0` / `npm 6.13.4` and `node v14.16.0` / `npm 7.8.0`. We had to update node and npm to fix this issue.

Please, use this answer only as a "last chance". No need to update/rollback your node/npm environment immediately when you see this error.

Comment: This just happened for me - working on my dev machine with node 16, failing on a host with node 14. Upgraded the host to node 16 and it works. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

For those running into this with Vue 3 and Yarn Berry, keep in mind that Vue 3  plugins are still not compatible with Yarn 2.*, so you'd have to update `vue-loader` section in your `.yarnrc.yml`as follows:

```yaml
  vue-loader@*:
    peerDependencies:
      '@vue/compiler-sfc': '*'
      webpack: '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

I get an error when I install it directly. but it worked when I forced it.;

```
npm i @vue/compiler-sfc --force
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve it by the following steps:

```
npm update
```

then use

```
npm i @vue/compiler-sfc
```